# Elastic search Like

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Hi I want to search a AUTHOR NAME with first and last name , My result was returned like this :

```
{
    "ABSTRACTER_ID": 8549,
    "AUTHOR_NAME": " Rombouts, George Paul, Nijmegen, Netherlands; Department of Pathology, RadboudUMC",
    "PRESENTER": null,
     "AGE_GROUP_VALUE": null,
     "STUDY_TYPE": null,
     "PHASE_TYPE": null,
     "STUDY_DESIGN_TYPE": null,
     "TRIAL_PHASE_TYPE": null
}
```

this result will be returned if i search using "George Paul" or "G Paul". How can i write the query in elastic search

Answer (score 0):

If `AUTHOR_NAME` is `analyzed` then following query will work.

```
{
"query": {
  "query_string": {
     "default_field": "AUTHOR_NAME",
     "query": "George Paul "
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: AUTHOR_NAME is not analyzed, How i get this record when i search like 'G paul'

Comment: If AUTHOR_NAME is not analyzed,why do you suppose you can do a query of 'G Paul' on it ? :(